# Dynamodb partitioning behaviour

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with 1500 RCUS and it can scale up to 2000, but we had a traffic spike which caused the consumed RCUs to shoot up above 3000 which would've been handled by the burst capacities, I guess.

[image]

I'm aware of the dynamodb partition limits like 3000 RCUs, 1000 WCUs and 10G data.

So my question is, will these kind of spikes cause partitioning or not? If yes, where can I see the number of partitions in my table. I couldn't find it anywhere in the AWS console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burst capacity does not cause your table to create a new partition. [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html) are pretty clear that new partitions are caused by the size of your data and the amount of *provisioned* capacity.

> DynamoDB allocates additional partitions to a table in the following situations:
>
> •   If you increase the table's provisioned throughput settings beyond what the existing partitions can support.
>
> •   If an existing partition fills to capacity and more storage space is required.

There’s no way for you to view to number of partitions in your table. You *might* be able to find out by contacting AWS support.

That being said recent improvements to DynamoDB mean that you shouldn’t really have to worry about the number of partitions you have. Hot partitions are not a concern like they used to be because [DynamoDB adaptive capacity accommodates uneven data access patterns](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/).